# disable or remove dates from UIDatePicker in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

In my iPhone application I have a UIDatePicker for users to select delivery dates.
I want to disable or remove holidays and weekends in it.

I want to know how to disable or remove dates from UIDatePicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. You would have to write your own date picker based on `UIPickerView`.

Comment: What is the data source for the datepicker?

Comment: It must be a custom object that you write. If you look at the documentation for `UIDatePicker`, it actually mentions that it is not a subclass of `UIPickerView` but _contains_ a `UIPickerView`. Your architecture should be similar if you want to write your own date picker.